# How to show on the carousel a piece of the previous and next slide?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, react-elastic-carousel

I'm beginner in ReactJS and I would like to render the slides of my carousel showing a piece of the previous slide and also of the next slide, what I need to do is like this in the example below:

[image]

I am currently using the `react-elastic-carousel` library, but I am not attached to it, any library that works in ReactJS I am willing to use. Currently in my code, the slide is showing 100% of the space.

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-stonebraker-5mj4w?file=/src/App.js:0-518):

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Carousel from "react-elastic-carousel";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel itemsToShow={1} initialActiveIndex={3}>
        <div className="div">1</div>
        <div className="div">2</div>
        <div className="div">3</div>
        <div className="div">4</div>
        <div className="div">5</div>
        <div className="div">6</div>
        <div className="div">7</div>
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to show some of the previous and next slides by changing the overflow on the slider-container:

```
.rec.rec-slider-container {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

I would also put `overflow-x: hidden;` on your body so that it doesn't scroll left and right.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-https-pvg8h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)